# Firestore python functions not getting triggered

Tags: python, firebase, triggers, google-cloud-firestore

I have created a simple python function with just a print("triggered") and deployed with this command:

```
gcloud functions deploy hello_world --runtime python37 --trigger-event providers/cloud.firestore/eventTypes/document.create --trigger-resource projects/my-project-name/databases/default/documents/testing/{testId}
```

Tried also with providers/cloud.firestore/eventTypes/document.write

However, when I create a new document in /testing/ the function is not triggered at all.

I tried with firebase storage trigger and it works.

Is there a bug or something? or am I the one bugged?